# The joint distribution for a hierarchical Bayes model

Tags: bayesian, hierarchical-bayesian

Consider the following hierarchical Bayes model. We observe random variables $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$ conditionally independent and having Poisson distributions $X_i \sim Poiss(m_i\theta_i)$, where $m_i$ are known multipliers and $\theta_i$ are unknown parameters. Assume that $\theta_1, ..., \theta_n$ are independet random variables with the same distribution $Gamma(\alpha, \lambda)$. Parameter $\lambda$ is a random variable with $Gamma(\beta, \sigma)$ distribution. Hyperparameters $\alpha, \beta, \sigma$ are known.

I would like to compute the the joint distribution.

Is the following computation correct?

$P(X_1, X_2, ..., X_n|\theta_1, \theta_2, ..., \theta_n) P(\theta_1, \theta_2, ..., \theta_n| \lambda) P(\lambda) =$
$= \prod \limits_{i=1}^n P(X_i|\theta_1, \theta_2, ..., \theta_n) \prod \limits_{i=1}^n P(\theta_i|\lambda) P(\lambda) = $
$
\prod \limits_{i=1}^n \frac{(m_i\theta_i)^{x_i}}{x_i!} e^{-m_i\theta_i} \prod \limits_{i=1}^n \frac{\lambda^{\alpha}}{\Gamma(\alpha)} \theta_i^{\alpha-1}e^{-\lambda\theta_i} \frac{\sigma^{\beta}}{\Gamma(\beta)} \lambda^{\beta-1} e^{-\sigma \lambda}
$

(Next step is to propose Gibbs sampler.)

Comment: How do you define the likelihood? I ask because the likelihood is typically expressed as $p(\bf x | \Theta)$ where $\bf x$ represents the observations and $\Theta$ represents the model parameters.

Comment: I was hoping to follow the definition you mentioned. Next step is to propose Gibbs sampler.

Comment: I see. To implement the Gibbs sampler (in my experience) we often use the joint distributions of the observations and the parameters, $p( \bf x , \Theta)$, which looks like what you've found.

Comment: The next step would be to obtain the full conditional distributions for $\theta_1, \ldots, \theta_n$, and $\lambda$.

Comment: I see. You are of course right :) Thanks :) I will edit the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the right way. Observe that

$$p(\theta_{1:n}, \lambda \vert x_{1:n}) = \prod \limits_{i=1}^n \frac{(m_i\theta_i)^{x_i}}{x_i!} e^{-m_i\theta_i} \prod \limits_{i=1}^n \frac{\lambda^{\alpha}}{\Gamma(\alpha)} \theta_i^{\alpha-1}e^{-\lambda\theta_i} \frac{\sigma^{\beta}}{\Gamma(\beta)} \lambda^{\beta-1} e^{-\sigma \lambda} \\
\propto \prod \limits_{i=1}^n (m_i\theta_i)^{x_i} e^{-m_i\theta_i} \prod \limits_{i=1}^n \lambda^{\alpha} \theta_i^{\alpha-1}e^{-\lambda\theta_i}  \lambda^{\beta-1} e^{-\sigma \lambda}.$$

To sample $\lambda | \theta_{1:n}$, it is easy to see that
$$p(\lambda \vert x_{1:n}, \theta_{1:n}) \propto \prod \limits_{i=1}^n \lambda^{\alpha} e^{-\lambda\theta_i}  \lambda^{\beta-1} e^{-\sigma \lambda} = \lambda^{\alpha+\beta-1} e^{-\lambda(\sigma + \sum_{i=1}^n \theta_i)},$$
which is a Gamma distribution with parameters $(\alpha + \beta, \sigma + \sum_{i=1}^n \theta_i)$. Note that the data does not inform us about $\lambda$.

Conversely, to sample $\theta_{1:n} | \lambda, x_{1:n}$ we have

$$p(\theta_{1:n} | \lambda, x_{1:n}) \propto \prod \limits_{i=1}^n (m_i\theta_i)^{x_i} e^{-m_i\theta_i}  \theta_i^{\alpha-1}e^{-\lambda\theta_i} = \frac{1}{\prod_{i=1}^n m_i^{\alpha-1}} \prod \limits_{i=1}^n (m_i\theta_i)^{x_i} e^{-m_i\theta_i}  (m_i\theta_i)^{\alpha-1}e^{-\lambda\theta_i} \\
\propto  \prod \limits_{i=1}^n (m_i\theta_i)^{x_i + \alpha - 1} e^{-(m_i + \lambda)\theta_i} \\
\propto \prod \limits_{i=1}^n \theta_i^{x_i + \alpha - 1} e^{-(m_i + \lambda)\theta_i}, $$
such that each $\theta_i | \lambda, x_i$ is proportional to a Gamma distribution with parameters $(x_i + \alpha, m_i + \lambda)$. These can be sampled independently across multiple processors.

Comment: Thanks so much! Unfortunately I do not have high enough reputation to give you an UpVote :)

Comment: No worries, just make sure that you verify I've gotten it anywhere near correct :-)

Comment: It's very typical to confuse the product notation: $$\prod_{i=1}^n c = c^n$$ Using some parentheses will reveal your mistakes.